# What am I doing wrong: sortable list supporting drag & drop for Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

This is my code:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div id="herschik-helper" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center" style="display:none; margin-bottom: 15px;">
   1. Drag and sort<br>2. When finished click Save
  </div>
 </div>
 <ul class="list-unstyled" id="sortable">';

    while($aRow = $selectTabbladen->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ......

    print '
     <li id="tabid_li_'.$tab_id.'">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
       <a href="#" id="'.$tab_id.'" name="'.$tab_name.'" class="tab_data" role="button">
        <div class="panel panel-box">
         <div class="panel-top"><img src="'.$pad.$tab_icon.'"></div>
         <div class="panel-info">
          <span class="ng-scope">'.$tab_name.'</span>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-bottom bg-light">
          <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>';
          <span class="badge-notify">'.$aantal.'</span>
         </div>
        </div>
       </a>                    
      </div>
     </li>';
```

script:

```
$('.herSchikken').on('click',function() {
    $('#herschik-helper').slideDown('slow');
    $('.herSchikken').html('<i class="fa fa-save"></i>');
    $('.herSchikken').prop("id","opslaan");
    $('.herSchikken').prop("title","Opslaan");
    $('.tab_data').css("cursor","move");
    $('ul#sortable').sortable({ tolerance: 'pointer' });

    $("#opslaan").click(function( e ) {
        if( !$("#opslaan c").length ) {
            $('.herSchikken').html('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>');
            $('ul#sortable').sortable('destroy');
            $('#herschik-helper').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" style="font-size: 25px; color: #fff;"></i>');
            var h = [];
            $('ul#sortable li').each(function() {  h.push($(this).attr('id').substr(9));  });
            alert (h);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "herschikken_update.php",
                data: {ids: " " + h + ""},
                success: function(html) {
                    window.location.reload();
                    //showTabbladen(html);
                }
            }); 
            return false;
        }   
        e.preventDefault();     
    });
});
```

everything works except dragging and sorting. I've tried everything:

```
   connectWith: "....",
   items: "...",
   revert: true,
   placeholder: 'placeholder',
   forceHelperSize: true,
   zIndex: 9999
```

data is being read from the database. you get 4 rows of 4 cols. I want to sort any col where I want.

In my case, if I want to move a col then everything is moving. you can not see clearly witch col i have clicked and where i want to move it.

Who can help me to realize this and also indicate how to handle it the best way with a placeholder?

If i delete this line, everything is displayed below the other:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
```

but then I can sort everything.

how can I make this work without removing this line? This is similar to what I want http://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/1064q7jm/

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

I replacd this line:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="sortable"><li>....
```

whith this:

```
<div class="row sortable">
```